# User to Profile link Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am very new to Laravel and would like some clarity.

I am trying to Link two tables: `Users => Profiles`

`Users` looks like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('displayName');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('role')->nullable();
    $table->string('department')->nullable();
    $table->string('location')->nullable();
    $table->string('directDialIn')->nullable();
    $table->string('mobileNumber')->nullable();
    $table->string('managedByUsername')->nullable();
    $table->string('managedByDisplayName')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`Profiles` looks like this:

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('user_username')->index();
    $table->mediumText('skills');
    $table->mediumText('background');
    $table->mediumText('socialProfiles');
    $table->string('displayPicture')->default('../../assets/images/user_pic.jpg');
    $table->string('mangedByUsername');
    $table->boolean('changesPending')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The relevant models

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Primary key to use
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'username';

    /**
     * Tell Eloquent to not auto increment
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * Table to use
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'displayName', 'email', 
        'role', 'department', 'location', 
        'directDialIn', 'mobileNumber', 'managedByUsername',
        'managedByDisplayName'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the profile associated with this user
     */
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_username');
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get the user that has this Profile
    */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_username');
    }
}
```

According to the documentation:

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method:

So I have explicitly defined the keys to be used.

In my routes I have:

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfileController@index');
```

I am quite used to just joining two tables with an SQL JOIN but in this case, how do I get both the User model data and the Profile Model data?

So it'd be like: User: Dave then Dave's profile.

Also, if Dave hasn't filled in his profile could I display just his user data?

In `ProfilesController` I have this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // Get this user's username from the session
    $username = $request->session()->get('User_name');

    /**
     * Get the Profile and associated User by pulling from the database via user_username
     * Will return a profile with an attached user
     */
    $profile = Profile::with('user')->where('user_username', $username)->first();

    return view('pages.profile.show', compact('profile'));
}
```

However, when I dump out the result for `Profile` the associated `User` is null.

I find this strange as I can use `Artisan tinker` as follows:

`$profile = App\Profile::find(7);`

and then...

`$profile->user`

Which yeilds the user relating to a Profile with an ID of 7.

A `dd($profile);` yeilds the following:

[image]

Profiles table

[image]

Users table

[image]

As you can see, there is data is both tables and `user_username` is the same as `username` but for some reason when using `with::` the link between the two just isn't seen.

Comment: Which is the foreign key in `Profile` model? If it is `user_username` then you should specify it in your model or relation. Because Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the Profile model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key.

Comment: I'll update my question to show a more detailed spec

Comment: does your `$profile` has data? How do you access the relation? Is it like `$profile->user` ?

Comment: That's exactly how I'm attempting it.

Comment: please add the `dd($profile);` result from `index()` method. before return statement.

Comment: I will add it to the answer.

Comment: can you add some table rows for both tables? Are you sure there is a user with `username = jesseo` ? Nothing else seems to a have a problem!!

Comment: I have made some test and everything works perfect when relation defined as `public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_username', 'username');
    }` but returns null when relation defined as `public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_username'');
    }`. I can't find any other reason for the `null` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with()` method

```
$profile_with_user = Profile::with('user')->where('user_username', $username)->first();
```

Or

```
$user_with_profile = User::with('profile')->where('username', $username)->first();
```

Comment: So, in this sense, if I'm going through the Profiles Model is it not better to use the first instance?